# How to insert other column on pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to make report, since it's take too long on website so I build the query, but I can't insert other column on pivot.

On example data each training have different names, score and time @user

```
create table TBL_USER (
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  USERNAME varchar(50),
);
create table TBL_TRAINING(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  NM_TRAINING varchar(255),
);
create table TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING(
  ID_DETAIL int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ID_TRAINING int,
  ID_USER varchar(50),
  SCORE int,
  TIME time,
);

INSERT INTO TBL_USER VALUES ('AA')
INSERT INTO TBL_USER VALUES ('BB')
INSERT INTO TBL_USER VALUES ('CC')

INSERT INTO TBL_TRAINING VALUES ('T_1')
INSERT INTO TBL_TRAINING VALUES ('T_2')
INSERT INTO TBL_TRAINING VALUES ('T_3')

INSERT INTO TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING VALUES ('1','1','80','00:50:00')
INSERT INTO TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING VALUES ('1','2','40','00:40:00')
INSERT INTO TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING VALUES ('1','3','60','00:10:00')
INSERT INTO TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING VALUES ('2','1','30','00:30:00')
INSERT INTO TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING VALUES ('2','2','40','00:50:00')
INSERT INTO TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING VALUES ('2','3','50','00:30:00')
INSERT INTO TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING VALUES ('3','1','100','00:50:00')
INSERT INTO TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING VALUES ('3','2','80','00:50:00')
INSERT INTO TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING VALUES ('3','3','70','00:30:00')

Sample Data
| ID_USER | Username | Name_Training | Score | Time     |
|---------|----------|---------------|-------|----------|
| 1       | AA       | T_1           | 80    | 00:50:00 |
| 2       | BB       | T_1           | 40    | 00:40:00 |
| 3       | CC       | T_1           | 60    | 00:10:00 |
| 1       | AA       | T_2           | 30    | 00:30:00 |
| 2       | BB       | T_2           | 40    | 00:50:00 |
| 3       | CC       | T_2           | 50    | 00:30:00 |
| 1       | AA       | T_3           | 100   | 00:50:00 |
| 2       | BB       | T_3           | 80    | 00:50:00 |
| 3       | CC       | T_3           | 70    | 00:30:00 |

Expected results
| ID_USER | Username | T_1 | Time_T_1 | T_2 | Time_T_2 | T_3 | Time_T_3 |
|---------|----------|-----|----------|-----|----------|-----|----------|
| 1       | AA       | 80  | 00:50:00 | 30  | 00:30:00 | 100 | 00:50:00 |
| 2       | BB       | 40  | 00:40:00 | 40  | 00:50:00 | 80  | 00:50:00 |
| 3       | CC       | 60  | 00:10:00 | 50  | 00:30:00 | 70  | 00:30:00 |
```

```
declare @idtraining as nvarchar (max)
declare @ScriptPivot as nvarchar (max)
declare @ScriptFinal as nvarchar (max)

// GET ALL NAME TRAINING FOR PIVOT
select @ScriptPivot =   SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + '['+CAST(NM_TRAINING AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+']'    
                    FROM TBL_TRAINING
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 

set @ScriptFinal = SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT C.ID, C.USERNAME, A.NM_TRAINING, B.SCORE, B.TIME 
    FROM TBL_TRAINING A
    JOIN TBL_DETAIL_TRAINING B ON B.ID_TRAINING = A.ID
    JOIN TBL_USER C ON C.ID = B.ID_USER 
    -- LOT JOIN HERE
) AS SOURCETABLE PIVOT (MAX(SCORE) FOR NM_TRAINING IN ([T_1],[T_2],[T_3])) AS PIVOTTABLE

--print @ScriptFinal
```

So far I only know add 1 column (training or time).

I can add another column time by adding pivot script again but it is added at the last column and I get more than 100 training names.

I tried using a temp table then using a pivot but I can't figure out how to insert the column times on the list column.
Is there a way to get the same result?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: ` WHERE B.ID = @idtraining` or 111, does not make sense, could you add it?

Comment: do you need dynamic pivot? how many training times are you likely to have?

Comment: this question is probably the most popular sql server question there is, i'm surprised you weren't able to find multiple columns dynamic pivot

Comment: @Horaciux as I said it's only for reports, so it's not dynamic. 1 training has many sub-trainings.

Comment: @siggemannen I found a lot of column cases but it's not the same problem, mostly adding a column on the last column, in my case I needed to insert the second column on the pivot like this : | pivot | add a second column | pivot |

Comment: I don't get the comment you tag me. Add complete schema, tables involved, and data sample. What on Earth is `B.ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Not a complete answer, but you can work from this.

I still don't understand the use of `@idtraining`.

I added more training so you can see how dynamically added as columns.

```
CREATE TABLE UserTraining (
    ID_USER INTEGER,
    Username VARCHAR(255),
    Training VARCHAR(255),
    Score INTEGER,
    Time TIME
);

INSERT INTO UserTraining (ID_USER, Username, Training, Score, Time) VALUES
    (1, 'AA', 'T_1', 80, '00:50:00'),
    (2, 'BB', 'T_1', 40, '00:40:00'),
    (3, 'CC', 'T_1', 60, '00:10:00'),
    (1, 'AA', 'T_2', 30, '00:30:00'),
    (2, 'BB', 'T_2', 40, '00:50:00'),
    (3, 'CC', 'T_2', 50, '00:30:00'),
      (3, 'CC', 'T_7', 50, '00:30:00'),
    (1, 'AA', 'T_3', 100, '00:50:00'),
    (2, 'BB', 'T_3', 80, '00:50:00'),
      (2, 'BB', 'T_5', 80, '00:50:00'),
    (3, 'CC', 'T_3', 70, '00:30:00');



DECLARE @pivotColumns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Get the distinct training names for Score and Time
SELECT @pivotColumns = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + QUOTENAME(Training + '_Score') + ', ' + QUOTENAME(Training + '_Time')
                               FROM UserTraining 
                               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')

-- Build the dynamic pivot query
SET @sql = '
    WITH ScoreTable AS (
        SELECT ID_USER, Username, Training + ''_Score'' AS Training, CAST(Score AS NVARCHAR) AS Value
        FROM UserTraining
    ), 
    TimeTable AS (
        SELECT ID_USER, Username, Training + ''_Time'' AS Training, CAST(Time AS NVARCHAR) AS Value
        FROM UserTraining
    )
    SELECT ID_USER, Username, ' + @pivotColumns + '
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM ScoreTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM TimeTable
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Value)
        FOR Training IN (' + @pivotColumns + ')
    ) AS PivotTable
    ORDER BY ID_USER'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

| ID_USER | Username | T_1_Score | T_1_Time | T_2_Score | T_2_Time | T_3_Score | T_3_Time | T_5_Score | T_5_Time | T_7_Score | T_7_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 80 | 00:50:00.0000000 | 30 | 00:30:00.0000000 | 100 | 00:50:00.0000000 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | BB | 40 | 00:40:00.0000000 | 40 | 00:50:00.0000000 | 80 | 00:50:00.0000000 | 80 | 00:50:00.0000000 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | CC | 60 | 00:10:00.0000000 | 50 | 00:30:00.0000000 | 70 | 00:30:00.0000000 | *null* | *null* | 50 | 00:30:00.0000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3lcqEXfv)

This is the resulting dynamic query:

```
 WITH ScoreTable AS (
        SELECT ID_USER, Username, Training + '_Score' AS Training, CAST(Score AS NVARCHAR) AS Value
        FROM UserTraining
    ), 
    TimeTable AS (
        SELECT ID_USER, Username, Training + '_Time' AS Training, CAST(Time AS NVARCHAR) AS Value
        FROM UserTraining
    )
    SELECT ID_USER, Username, [T_1_Score], [T_1_Time], [T_2_Score], [T_2_Time], [T_3_Score], [T_3_Time], [T_5_Score], [T_5_Time], [T_7_Score], [T_7_Time]
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM ScoreTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM TimeTable
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Value)
        FOR Training IN ([T_1_Score], [T_1_Time], [T_2_Score], [T_2_Time], [T_3_Score], [T_3_Time], [T_5_Score], [T_5_Time], [T_7_Score], [T_7_Time])
    ) AS PivotTable
    ORDER BY ID_USER
```